# How to change color of 1sprites with other sprites dynamically?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to the cocos2dx I have created 2 sprites with two different colors.Now I want to change the color of the sprites dynamically with other sprites color when I touch on the  sprites. Is there any predefined function to change the color dynamically in c++ ?

```
Right = CCSprite::create("frog1.png");
Right->setPosition(ccp(250,300));
this->addChild(Right,1);

Wrong = CCSprite::create("frog2.png");
Wrong->setPosition(ccp(250,300));
this->addChild(Wrong,1);
```

These are my two sprites. Now how to change frog1 color with frog2 color dynamically when it is touched or frog2.png color with with frog1.png when it is touched ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `touch events` that your layer will respond to (since this is Cocos2d-x v2 and not v3). That involves subclassing `CCLayer` and `CCTargetedTouchDelegate`. You then add your listeners so that when the layer gets a touch you can loop through your Sprites and decide which is touched and then swap textures. This is general advice. To implement it have a look at: http://paralaxer.com/touch-tutorial-player-movement/